# how to talk HR about interview

Tags: interviewing, communication, salary, human-resources, negotiation

I have talked to an HR regarding a job opportunity and we had a discussion about [CTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_to_company). After that, HR sent me a mail regarding the discussed points.

> As we discussed your CTC will be '00.00'.

So should I tell truth to HR or no need?

Comment: For people like me who had never heard about CTC, it means "Cost To Company. It means total salary package and benefits received by employee in a year including free meals, cabs, interest free loans. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer would be : it depends.

- In case the difference is small (i.e., the amount is rounded off to the nearest whole number), then probably that is okay.
- In case there is a big difference, you should bring it up.

There is a possibility that, according to the organizational policies, the package you ought to get is higher than you quoted, and they are offering you the company-standard package (which is higher than your expected number).

However, given that you have interview scheduled, you don't want to lose a chance because of any human errors in communication. So, if there is a big difference, better to have it clarified with HR.

After all, we all want to *earn* our paychecks.

Comment: The diff  is of 1 lakh. Is that big amount?

Comment: @Arvindraja Is the final amount a round figure? like 10 LPA, 20LPA..?

Comment: No final amount has for example from 8.5 to 9.5, it becomes that way

Comment: @Arvindraja Well, in that case, I'd say clear it up with HR upfront and then go for interview.